# Global variable in Javascript, rerurn wrong value

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my program. I had a "tempName" variable. It is a global variable. I set value for it in "ktDN" function and get value in another function "loadMain" but it has "undefined".
Please help me!! Thanks you so much!!

```
var tempName;
var tempPosititon;
function ktDN() {
    for(var x=0; x < mangNhanVien.length; x++)
    {
        if(document.getElementById("txtUser").value == mangNhanVien[x].user &&
            document.getElementById("txtPass").value == mangNhanVien[x].pass)
        {
            tempName = mangNhanVien[x].ten;
            tempPosititon = mangNhanVien[x].position;
            alert(tempName +" "+tempPosititon);//debug ==> right value
            //alert("Dang nhap thanh cong");
            window.open("../HTML/main.html");
            window.open('','_self').close();
            return true;
        }
    }
    alert("Tai khoan dang nhap khong chinh xac");
}
function logout() {
    window.open("../HTML/login.html");
    window.open('','_self').close();
}
function loadMain() {
    document.getElementById("lblUser").innerHTML = tempName; //==> wrong value,         it is "undefined" 
    document.getElementById("lblPosition").innerHTML = tempPosititon;
    var s = "<label for='lstNV'>Tìm kiếm:</label><input list='lstNV'><datalist id='lstNV'>";
    for( x in mangNhanVien)
    {
        s += "<option value='"+mangNhanVien[x].ten+"'></option>";
    }
    s += "</datalist>";
    document.getElementById("timNV").innerHTML = s;
    var tbl = "<table><tr><th>STT</th><th>HỌ TÊN</th><th>GIỚI TÍNH</th><th>NGÀY SINH</th><th>CMND</th><th>ĐỊA CHỈ</th><th>SỐ ĐIỆN THOẠI</th><th>NGÀY VÀO LÀM</th><th>NGÀY NGHỈ</th></tr>"
    for( x in mangNhanVien)
    {
        tbl += "<tr><td>"+mangNhanVien[x].maSo+"</td><td>"+mangNhanVien[x].ten+"</td><td>"+mangNhanVien[x].gioiTinh+"</td><td>"+mangNhanVien[x].ngaySinh+"</td><td>"+mangNhanVien[x].CMND+"</td><td>"+mangNhanVien[x].diaChi+"</td><td>"+mangNhanVien[x].sdt+"</td><td>"+mangNhanVien[x].ngayVaoLam+"</td><td>"+mangNhanVien[x].ngayNghi+"</td></tr>";
    }
    tbl += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("tblNV").innerHTML = tbl;
}
```

Comment: where is KDTN() called,is it called before loadMain,if not tempName would be undefined ,as you have not given any value to tempName intially

Comment: `mangNhanVien` contains the cleartext passwords of other users? And is available on the client?

Comment: `mangNhanVien` has 9 elements but one of them has user and password

Comment: the password is clear and available on the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you ktDN function must be called before you use the global variable value in loadMain function.

Also use a default value for tempName like:

```
var tempName = 'default value';
```

Comment: I am sure that ktDN function be called before loadMain function because the ktDN function is in the login page and loadMain function is in the main page. I tried to set default name for it but it doesn't work

Comment: If you have two different pages then each page on reload will setup you JS again so you need to make sure the ktDN is called on each page before loadMain